# Group dateTime by hour range

Tags: c#, linq

I got a list like this:

```
class Article
{
...
Public DateTime PubTime{get;set}
...
}

List<Article> articles
```

Now I want to group this list with hour range :[0-5,6-11,12-17,18-23]

I know there is a cumbersome way to do this:

```
var firstRange = articles.Count(a => a.PubTime.Hour >= 0 && a.PubTime.Hour <= 5);
```

But I want to use a elegant way. How can I do that?Use Linq Or anything others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `Hour / 6`:

```
var grouped = articles.GroupBy(a => a.PubTime.Hour / 6);
IDictionary<int, int> CountsByHourGrouping = grouped.ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

The key in the dictionary is the period (0 representing 0-5, 1 representing 6-11, 2 representing 12-17, and 3 representing 18-23). The value is the count of articles in that period.

Note that your dictionary will only contain values where those times existed in the source data, so it won't always contain 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a `CheckRange` Function, which takes your values and returns a `bool`. To make your code more reusable and elegant.

**Function Example:**

```cs
bool CheckRange (this int number, int min, int max) 
    => return (number >= min && number <= max);
```

You could now use this function to check if the `PubTime.Hour` is in the correct timelimit.

**Implementation Example:**

```cs
var firstRange = articles.Count(a => a.CheckRange(0, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks dude!!!!The extend method is a  really good way to simplify my code